# SQL Server: import date in yyy-mm-dd from csv in dd-mmm-yy

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm receiving a csv with dates in a dd-mmm-yy format

```
05-SEP-19
```

I want to convert them into yyyy-mm-dd

```
2019-09-05
```

When I import the file with Microsoft Server Management Studio.

Comment: You should be converting them to `date`'s, which don't have a format.

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format. the reason you're seeing it in `yyyy-MM-dd` format is likely because that's the default format for SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
This converts string to date format, after this you can format date as you want...

```
DECLARE @String nvarchar(30);
SET @String = '05-SEP-19'

SELECT @String, CONVERT(date,substring(@String, 1, 2) + ' ' + 
                             substring(@String, 4, 3) + ' ' + 
                             substring(@String, 8, 4), 6)
```

Results:

```
05-SEP-19   2019-09-05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '05-SEP-19'
PRINT @dt
DECLARE @dts VARCHAR(20) = FORMAT(@dt, 'yyy-MM-dd')
PRINT @dts
```

gives

```
Sep  5 2019 12:00AM
2019-09-05

Completion time: 2019-11-22T11:16:43.8140327+02:00
```

Note that @dt has type DATETIME.   What this piece of script does is (i) create DATETIME @dt initialised from a string containing an "acceptably recognisable" representation of a date (ii) display @dt default format (iii) create string initialised with custom-format of this value (iv) display that.

You have to distinguish between the (date) type and its formatted-for-display (string) representation.

Comment: It comes as string [DT_STR] when I import I get it as yyyy-mm-dd into my date Data Type. Cant I add something in Default Value or Binding to convert it directly when I import?

Comment: Problem: I can't visualise exactly where you are working.  Have you tried simple cast?  `(DT_DATE)fieldname` where `fieldname` is `DT_STR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(50)
SET @Date='05-SEP-19'

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date), 120) AS Date
```

**Output**

```
Date
-----
2019-09-05
```